# Which is the quickest way to change apostrophes to quotation marks?

Tags: sigil

I am proofreading a text, and I would like to change all occurrences of ' to the relevant character, ‘ or ’; ditto per " and double quotes. 
The task cannot be automated, because there are apostrophes in the middle of the text, like in "I'm", and of course " is heavily used in the XHTML markup. At the moment I am using Sigil, but replacing every single character takes a bit of time because of the tidying involved. Do you know of any better way?

Comment: btw, I had some partial results by changing first all occurrences of 's, n't, 've, 'll, and then using a regex changing '([^']*)' to ‘\1’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [PunctuationSmarten Sigil plugin](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=247088).